# How do I configure NHibernate (or Fluent NHib) to add a table name prefix to all table names?

Tags: visual-studio, orm, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, naming-conventions

In the current application I'm developing I'm using Fluent NHibernate to configure NHibernate for use as an ORM.  I want to be able to add a prefix to all the table names used in the application, so that if I use a database that is already servicing another application, there are no naming conflicts between the two applications.

So for instance if I wanted to add a prefix of `Portal_` to each table, the `Users` table would become `Portal_Users`.

Of course, I know how to configure each table name in each mapping file, but that's not really a good solution for what I'm trying to do.  If I ever wanted to change the prefix, I would be forced to change each of the mapping files. I want to be able to add (or change) the prefix to all the table names in a single place in my code or configuration.

**How does one add a prefix to all table names within an application using NHibernate (or Fluent NHibernate)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fluent implementation..

```
 public class AutoPersistenceModelGenerator : IAutoPersistenceModelGenerator
    {
        public AutoPersistenceModel Generate()
        {
            var mappings = new AutoPersistenceModel();
            mappings.AddEntityAssembly(typeof(User).Assembly).Where(GetAutoMappingFilter);
            mappings.Conventions.Setup(GetConventions());

.....
    private Action<IConventionFinder> GetConventions()
    {
        return c =>
        {
            c.Add<PrimaryKeyConvention>();
            c.Add<ReferenceConvention>();
            c.Add<HasManyConvention>();
            c.Add<TableNameConvention>();
```

......

```
       public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention
        {
            public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IClassInstance 
instance)
            {
                instance.Table(Inflector.Net.Inflector.Pluralize("Portal_" + 
    instance.EntityType.Name));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your own [INamingStrategy](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html_single/#configuration-namingstrategy) and specify it for your Configuration:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.SetNamingStrategy(new MyTablePrefixStrategy());
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and by far the easiest way to achieve it!